# Как связать компоненты?

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Существует два компонента: проигрыватель и треклист.
В проигрывателе содержится встроенные для тега `audio` - `currentTime` и `duration`. Необходимо отобразить их разницу в компоненте треклист.
Можно ли это сделать? Если да, то как?